# realm mobile platform - can realm be used as a database?

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

With the new realm version there is new cloud capability, where users can sync their data between all of their devices. I want to create a Main database where all the users store their information in this database, so each user could access the other user information.

Is there a way to do it? My database is going to contain a lot of data and is going to be very complex (storing thousands of images for each users).

So I would like to be able to access the database, but not to download it to the device and not to sync it (the on device database will not change every time image that is not related to the device will change).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Realm-Database`. However, as far as I do understand, the synchronization offered by the new `Realm` Object Server is not conditional: you either sync the entire DB or you don't. Additionally, `Realm` is **offline first**, meaning that the entire DB will be on your device at any given moment.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. This is very sad that they didn't add this feature, because sometimes you want to access the database on the server to check the information without need to store the entire database on your device.

Comment: That's a feature called partial replication. And it's definitely on the roadmap. :)

Comment: Thanks for the info! And thanks you and all the realm folks for the great product!