# Realm Swift: Question about Query-based public database

Tags: ios, swift, synchronization, realm

I’ve seen all around the documentation that Query-based sync is deprecated, so I’m wondering how should I got about my situation:

In my app (using Realm Cloud), I have a list of User objects with some information about each user, like their username. Upon user login (using Firebase), I need to check the whole User database to see if their username is unique. If I make this common realm using Full Sync, then all the users would synchronize and cache the whole database for each change right? How can I prevent that, if I only want the users to get a list of other users’ information at a certain point, without caching or re-synchronizing anything?

I know it's a possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758576/realm-mobile-platform-can-realm-be-used-as-a-database), but things have probably changed in four years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new MongoDB Realm gives you access to server level functions. This feature would allow you to query the list of existing users (for example) for a specific user name and return true if found or false if not (there are other options as well).

Check out the [Functions](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/functions/) documentation and there are some examples of how to call it from macOS/iOS in the [Call a function](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/ios/call-a-function/#ios-call-a-function) section

I don't know the use case or what your objects look like but an example function to calculate a sum would like something like this. This sums the first two elements in the array and returns their result;

```
your_realm_app.functions.sum([1, 2]) { sum, error in
   if let err = error {
      print(err.localizedDescription)
      return
   }

   if case let .double(x) = result {
      print(x)
   }    
}
```